# Why a variable length array compiles in this c++ program?

Tags: c++, arrays

It is said that arrays are allocated at compile time, then the size must be `const` and available at compile time.
**But the following example also works, Why?**

```
#include <iostream>                                  
#include <vector>                                                 
using namespace::std;                                             
int main()                                                       
{                                                    
    vector<int> ivec;                                               
    int k;                                                  
    while(cin>>k)                                              
        ivec.push_back(k);                                     
    int iarr[ivec.size()];                                           
    for (size_t k=0;k<ivec.size();k++)                                 
    {                                                             
        iarr[k]=ivec[k];                                               
        cout<<iarr[k]<<endl;                                   
    }                                                            
    return 0;                                                    
}
```

Comment: Clearly your assumptions aren't right then, yes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compile your code with `-pedantic`.
Most compilers support **[variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)** through **[compiler extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)**.
The code works due to the compiler extensions, However as you noted the code is non standard conforming and hence non portable.

Comment: Yes, with `-pedantic` it fails.

Comment: @flyingfoxlee: `-pedantic` disables all compiler specific and compiles the source code as per the strict specifications laid out by the C++ standard.So if you intend to write a portable code, always compile using `-pedantic`.I hope this answers your Q then.